# magento secure onepage checkout not working?

Tags: magento, ssl, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I am working on magento 1.7 version ultimento theme.
I enabled the secure url through admin panel(settings->configuration->web->secure-url)
now checkout page is secure but it not working fine.

after filled billing information press continue then shipping methoda showing after select any shipping method I pressed continue but only a loading image shows and nothing happened.

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look what's happening on the page with browser developers tools (console tab) the when you hit the button?